# Getting different Values when using groupby(column)["id"].nunique and trying to add a column using transform

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm trying to count the individual values per group in a dataset and add them as a new column to a table. The first one works, the second one produces wrong values.
When I use the following code
`unique_id_per_column = source_table.groupby("disease").some_id.nunique()`
I'll get

```
|    | disease                 | some_id |
|---:|:------------------------|--------:|
|  0 | disease1                |   121   |
|  1 | disease2                |     1   |
|  2 | disease3                |     5   |
|  3 | disease4                |     9   |
|  4 | disease5                |    77   |
```

These numbers seem to check out, but I want to add them to another table where I have already a column with all values per group.
So I used the following code
`table["unique_ids"] = source_table.groupby("disease").uniqe_id.transform("nunique")`
and I get the following table, with wrong numbers for every row except the first.

```
|    | disease                 |some_id |   unique_ids      |
|---:|:------------------------|-------:|------------------:|
|  0 | disease1                |   151  |               121 |
|  1 | disease2                |     1  |               121 |
|  2 | disease3                |     5  |               121 |
|  3 | disease4                |     9  |               121 |
|  4 | disease5                |    91  |               121 |
```

I've expected that I will get the same results as in the first table. Anyone knows why I get the number for the first row repeated instead of correct numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) if need create column in another `DataFrame`:

```
s = source_table.groupby("disease").some_id.nunique()

table["unique_ids"] = table["disease"].map(s)
```

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I've misspelled my question, but I have already created the second table except the unique_IDs column I wanted to add, but when I try to add this I only get the wrong 121 values, instead of the right values shown in the first command

Comment: @albert180 - Answer was edited.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! Do you know why it didn't work using .transform()? I've seen it as an answer elsewhere on SO

Comment: @albert180 - because there is different stucture of data column `table["disease"]` like `source_table["disease"]`